# Wordpress conditional slider (Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

Complete newbie to PHP but not bad at cobbling together. I've started using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress which helps immensely.

I've got the code together that turns a gallery field into a jQuery slider (you chuck in the images in the back end and it loops through and creates the slider). However, what I'd like it to do is only load a static image if there is only one image entered. In psudo-code:

if field contains more than one image, loop through the slider code else (if there is only one image) just wrap the one image in img tags.

Current live code that generates the slider:

```
<?php

/* Create the Markup for a slider */

$images = get_field('hero_image_gallery');

if( $images ): ?>
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                    <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; 

?>
```

Any ideas? Initially I thought I'd want to count $images but I'm not sure that contains the number of images in the gallery.

**Edit:** Just dumped out the hero_image_gallery which starts:

array(2)

There's currently 2 images in there and if I add a third, I get array(3).

**Edit 2:** Full dump of hero_image_gallery below. I've had to edit out some details as I can only post 1 URL as a newbie.

array(2) { [0]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(971) ["alt"]=> string(14) "School" ["title"]=> string(12) "home-image-2" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(74) "#" ["width"]=> int(1260) ["height"]=> int(860) ["sizes"]=> array(9) { ["thumbnail"]=> string(74) "#" ["thumbnail-width"]=> int(150) ["thumbnail-height"]=> int(102) ["medium"]=> string(74) "#" ["medium-width"]=> int(300) ["medium-height"]=> int(204) ["large"]=> string(74) "#" ["large-width"]=> int(1024) ["large-height"]=> int(698) } } [1]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(977) ["alt"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(12) "home-image-1" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(74) "#" ["width"]=> int(1260) ["height"]=> int(860) ["sizes"]=> array(9) { ["thumbnail"]=> string(74) "#" ["thumbnail-width"]=> int(150) ["thumbnail-height"]=> int(102) ["medium"]=> string(74) "#" ["medium-width"]=> int(300) ["medium-height"]=> int(204) ["large"]=> string(74) "#" ["large-width"]=> int(1024) ["large-height"]=> int(698) } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have answered your own question! If you currently have 2 images, and when you view the returned array and it comes back with 2 results, then to check if you only have 1 image you would do something like this :

```
if( count($images) == 1 )
```

**Edit: added full code**

```
<?php

/* Create the Markup for a slider */

$images = get_field('hero_image_gallery');

if( $images && count($images) == 1 ) { ?>
   <!-- there is only 1 image -->
<?php } else if ( $images && count($images) > 1 ) { ?>
    <!-- there is more than 1 image -->
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                    <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My trouble is that I completely understand the concepts, I've just not learnt to properly code PHP yet (I'm a designer getting my hands "dirty").

Comment: You will get there! I've felt the best way to learn a language is through trial and error. Just think logically- when you added a third image it added something to the array. So you can infer (and verify through some testing) that 1 image would only return 1 result in an array.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I did get that part though :p

What I meant was I'm unsure how to write that up into a whole block of fully valid php!

Comment: Saw your update above with full code. You rock! 

I'll give it a go and also make sure to learn exactly what you did rather than just leech off you and the other good people here!

Comment: OK, so the slider still works with your code implemented but when I cut down to 1 image, it still outputs the slider code. It skips over the code looking for one image i.e. it outputs from <!-- there is more than 1 image --> down. I've pasted the full dump of hero_image_gallery in the OP above as it holds a fair amount of data. I guess that this is interfering?

Comment: Silly me- I left out a very important part of the code... and thats the count() method! I'll update my answer with the correct code. I'm sorry! :P

Comment: Aw man, again, you rock. Only just had a chance to try this but it worked (in a test environment anyway). Thanks again for your time, I'm learning!